# How to initialize a vector of TRUE in R?

Tags: r

Let's say I want to initialize a vector containing only `TRUE`, of a length `n`, where `n` is a positive integer.

Obviously, I can do `!logical(n)`, as well as `rep(TRUE,n)`.

However, I would like to know which of them is faster, and whether there are other (faster) alternatives.

Comment: You can use `microbenchmark` to find the speed

Comment: If you check `n <- 1e6; system.time(rep(TRUE, n))#
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0; system.time(!logical(n))#
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.05`, so the `rep` seems to be faster

Comment: @akrun thanks, `0 0 0` and `0.02 0.00 0.01` reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if the internal functions `rep_len()` or `rep.int()` are maybe faster.
That is not the case. `rep()` is the simplest option and just as fast as `rep_len()` .

```r
suppressMessages(require(microbenchmark))

n <- 1E6L
microbenchmark(
  rep(TRUE, n),
  rep_len(TRUE, n),
  rep.int(TRUE, n),
  !logical(n),
  !vector(length=n),
  times = 1E4L, units = "us"
)
#> Warning in microbenchmark(rep(TRUE, n), rep_len(TRUE, n), rep.int(TRUE, : Could
#> not measure a positive execution time for 1533 evaluations.
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>                 expr     min      lq       mean  median      uq      max neval
#>         rep(TRUE, n) 1203400 1494900 1943086.70 1546600 1627950 25343300 10000
#>     rep_len(TRUE, n) 1224500 1497100 1978824.31 1549950 1630400 28793600 10000
#>     rep.int(TRUE, n) 1281700 1558100 2026079.65 1609650 1692350 26135600 10000
#>          !logical(n) 2184300 2726350 3659910.07 2876200 3329900 28890700 10000
#>  !vector(length = n) 2158900 2729200 3626122.66 2872750 3296150 28172100 10000
#>                units       0       0      76.12     100     100     1400 10000
```

The reason why `logical()` and `vector()` are slower is obvious. They require
two operations instead of one: create the vector and change all values to `TRUE`
afterwards. Hence, we have to be aware that the speed advantage is not there for `FALSE` values: in that case `logical()` is even faster as `rep()`.

```r
microbenchmark(
  logical(n),
  vector(length=n),
  times = 1E4L, units = "us"
)
#> Warning in microbenchmark(logical(n), vector(length = n), times = 10000L, :
#> Could not measure a positive execution time for 4059 evaluations.
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>                expr    min     lq       mean median      uq      max neval
#>          logical(n) 461100 923400 1268676.20 985300 1110350 24575300 10000
#>  vector(length = n) 462400 923800 1268691.87 984850 1103850 25761700 10000
#>               units      0      0      19.45      0       0      900 10000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>